# Expl variable assignments not behaving as I expect

Tags: latex3, expl3, xparse

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.  Neither of the commented lines work as the uncommented version does.

```
\begin{filecontents}{silly.tex}
    This is just a test.
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setversion}{ m }
    {
            Hello I'm version \texttt{#1}.\par        
    }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVV}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ somm }
%\NewDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ somm }
    {
        \bool_set:Nn \l_ae_makeversions_star_bool       { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl    { #2 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_versionlist_tl  { #3 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_inputfile_tl    { #4 }
        \exp_args:NV \IfNoValueTF \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl 
                    {
                        TRUE:I have no value:\par
                        \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl { ; }
                    }
                    {
                        FALSE:\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl \par
                    }
                    Delimiter ~ is ~ \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl \par
%% In the following, I want the first commented out line of code to work.
%% Only one of the next FOUR lines should be left uncommented.
%        \seq_set_split:NVV \l_ae_version_seq  \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl  \l_ae_makeversions_versionlist_tl 
%        \seq_set_split:NnV \l_ae_version_seq { ; } \l_ae_makeversions_versionlist_tl 
%        \seq_set_split:Nxn \l_ae_version_seq { \tl_use:N \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter_tl  }{ #3 }
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_version_seq { ;  }{ #3 }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_version_seq { 
                                                 \setversion{##1}
                                                 \input{  \l_ae_makeversions_inputfile_tl }
                                                 \IfBooleanT { \l_ae_makeversions_star_bool } 
                                                             { \par\clearpage }
                                              }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\makeversions*{a;b;c;d}{silly}

\end{document}
```

I've made various attempts at generating variants for `\seq_set_split:N**` but to no avail.

## Addendum

I'm very aware that I could have defined `\makeversions` as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ s O{;} mm }
    {
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_versionlist  { #3 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_input_file   { #4 }
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_version_seq { ;  }{ #3 }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_version_seq { 
                                                 \setversion{##1}
                                                 \input{#4}
                                                 \IfBooleanT { #1 } 
                                                             { \par\clearpage }
                                              }
    }
```

But I would like to remind readers that this is a MWE.  My original code is much more complicated than the above example suggests.  The first MWE merely illustrates how I managed to boil my original problem down to something short and concise for this website.

In my original `\makeversions` calls another function which is context sensitive.  This new function, let's call is `\ae_makeversion_by_context` makes various decisions on how various parameters should be handled and then farms out the jobs to several other macros which then make further decisions.

For example, there is no universal default value for the *delimiter*.  As I change context, what constitutes the default also changes (this might sound wacky on the surface, but it makes sense within the type of documents my group needs to create).  But, I also do want to allow the user to override this *context dependent default value*.

Based upon the responses I've been getting, I'm beginning to think that, with regards to the *delimiter*, I should probably just create a boolean variable.  That is,  I could write something like

```
\bool_new:N \g_ae_makeversions_delimiter_override_bool
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ somm }
    {
        \IfNoValueTF {#2}
                    {
                        \bool_gset_true:N \g_ae_makeversions_delimiter_override_bool
                    }
                    {
                        \bool_gset_false:N \g_ae_makeversions_delimiter_override_bool
                    }
        ... < other code> ....    
    }
```

And that would probably be a better design decision.

So my original question boiled down to the following two questions:

- How do I get `\IfNoValue` to return the correct value if passed a token and not the raw input variable `#2`?
- How do I get `seq_set_split` to properly interpret tokens in its 2nd and 3rd arguments?

I kept these questions together because they seemed, at first blush, to revolve around the same issue.

@ScottH very nicely answered both of these questions.  I suspected there was still something deeper going on with `\IfNoValue`.  Hence I posted a [new question to address that matter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114896/expl-v-type-argument-no-fully-expanding-as-i-expected?lq=1).

I hope this better explains some of my *apparent* poor design decisions.

Comment: Your `IfNoValue` code isn't executing.  Probably (maybe), that code is written to taken an `n` type argument and can't deal with being passed a macro.

Comment: There are still problems if I replace the argument of `\IfNoValueT` with `#2`.

Comment: In that case add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVV}
` and use that in your set split with just the macro names, no braces (which works for me).

Comment: Please use the name convention of `expl`. Variables always end with the type. In your case `\l_ae_makeversions_input_file` should be `\l_ae_makeversions_input_file_tl`

Comment: @A.Ellett Good addendum.  I think you meant 2nd and 3rd arguments for `\seq_set_split:Nnn`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two occurrences of the same issue: using an `n` argument type when a `V` argument type is required.  When an `n`, or "no manipulation", argument type is specified the macro expects a brace group whose contents are passed untouched to the macro.  When a `V` argument type is specified, the macro expects a variable name as an argument, and the **V** alue, or replacement text, of that variable is passed to the macro.  Compare,

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {contents}

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\l_tmpa_tl}
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl

\tl_set:NV \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
```

Now where this occurs first is in

```
\IfNoValueT { \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter }
```

The macro `\IfNoValueT` is defined as

```
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfNoValueT \__xparse_if_no_value:nT
```

where we can see that it is an alias for an internal macro that expects an `n` type argument.  Thus, what is passed to `\__xparse_if_no_value:nT` is the *string*

```
"\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter"
```

rather than its contents,

```
-NoValue-
```

You can work around this by first replacing `\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter` with its contents using

```
\exp_args:NV \IfNoValueT \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter
```

where as the `V` indicates, the value of `\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter` is recovered.

---

The second spot where this happens is in

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_version_seq { \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter }{ \l_ae_makeversions_version_list }
```

where the contents of the second brace group are used as the delimiter, so the delimiter is set to be the string `"\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter"` which of course is not what was intended.  Rather, we want the *contents* of `\l_ae_makeversions_delimiter` to be used as the delimiter, and as such we need a `V` type argument.  A variant of `\seq_set_split` with the required argument types can be generated via:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVV}
```

and then used as in

```
\seq_set_split:NVV \l_ae_version_seq \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter \l_ae_makeversions_version_list
```

when all is as intended.

---

```
\begin{filecontents}{silly.tex}
    This is just a test.
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setversion}{ m }
    {
            Hello I'm version \texttt{#1}.\par        
    }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVV}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ somm }
    {
        \bool_set:Nn \l_ae_makeversions_star         { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter    { #2 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_version_list { #3 }
        \tl_set:Nn   \l_ae_makeversions_input_file   { #4 }
        \exp_args:NV \IfNoValueT \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter
                    {
                        \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter { ; }
                    }
%% In the following, I want the first commented out line of code to work.
%% Only one of the next THREE lines should be left uncommented.
        \seq_set_split:NVV \l_ae_version_seq \l_ae_makeversions_delimiter \l_ae_makeversions_version_list
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_version_seq { 
                                                 \setversion{##1}
                                                 \input{  \l_ae_makeversions_input_file }
                                                 \IfBooleanT { \l_ae_makeversions_star } 
                                                             { \par\clearpage }
                                              }
    }


\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\makeversions{a;b;c;d}{silly}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't fully agree with your assessment of what's happening with `\IfNoValueT`.  Unfortunately, I need to write something like `\IfNoValueT { \controlsequence }` which should still be read as an `n` type argument.

Comment: Fair enough, I could be wrong.  How do you interpret `\cs_new_eq:NN \IfNoValueT \__xparse_if_no_value:nT`?

Comment: Writing `\IfNoValueT { \controlsequence }` seems to me to be passing an `n` type argument.  I'm not writing `\IfNoValueT \controlsequence`.  If what you say is true, then this seems to quite a short-coming with `xparse`.

Comment: `n` type arguments (for the most part) are passed as is, there's no expansion or replacement.  So you're asking whether the _sting_ `\controlsequence` is equal to `-NoValue-`.  Can you use an optional with default value `;`?

Comment: I think I see what's happening.  In the documentation for `xparse`, it says that simply writing `\IfNoValue{-NoValue-}` will not result in `T`.  Somehow, my token list is be expanded into the string `-NoValue-`.  What a pain.

Comment: Why not use `\NewDocumentCommand{\makeversions}{ sO{;}mm }`?

Comment: What I'd like to know is where `\__xparse_if_no_value:nT` is defined and how I can pass the value of `-NoValue-` in the correct format from one macro to another so that `\IfNoValue` reads it correctly.

Comment: Your suggestions are useful, but this is a MWE, or rather Minimal nonWorking Example.  I need to pass the value and evaluate it later.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure the issue is because `-NoValue-` is becoming stringified...it's because `\controlsequence` isn't being replaced by it's contents.  I have a fix for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm going to accept your answer with regard to getting the *splitting* portion of my question to work.  I'm going to post a new question about `\IfNoValueTF`.  Let me reformulate my question and we can continue this discussion in my next post.

Comment: That might not be necessary, check whether my edit works for you.

Comment: Your edit definitely works.  But I'm very confused.  I don't agree with your interpretation of what's happening, but you've clearly solved this.  So, either I'm totally failing to understand something fundamental here or I'm completely missing the point of what you're talking about.  :(  Would you might caring to elaborate your point a bit more?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8819/discussion-between-scott-h-and-a-ellett)

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be doing a lot of assignments for no reason at all. Cutting your example down and 'tidying up', I get to

```
\begin{filecontents}{silly.tex}
    This is just a test.
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setversion}{m}
    {Hello I'm version \texttt{#1}.\par}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N  \l_ae_version_seq
\NewDocumentCommand { \makeversions } { s O { ; } m m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_version_seq {#2} {#3}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_version_seq
      { 
        \setversion {##1}
        \input {#4}
        \IfBooleanT #1 { \par\clearpage }
      }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\makeversions{a;b;c;d}{silly}

\end{document}
```

(Ideally, `\makeversions` and `\setversion` would point to code-level functions, but I think that might obscure the point here.)

What are the key points I've tried to pick up on?

- Variables should be declared
- Document-level commands where optional arguments have a default are handled 'correctly' using `O { <default> }` (part of the interface) rather than `o` plus a `\IfNoValue` test (part of the code)
- The `s` type returns a boolean which can be tested directly
- `\IfNoValue(TF)` and `\IfBoolean(TF)` are meant to be used *directly* on the input to make branching decisions, not on stored values

Comment: I suspect there may be more going on in the 'real' situation which might explain some of the odd decisions in the MWE in the question. I'll edit if that's the case!

Comment: The asker seems convinced that my answer is incorrect, if that's the case (aside from using the word string when I maybe shouldn't have etc.) I wouldn't mind knowing what I've misunderstood!

Comment: @ScottH. Your answer looks broadly correct, although I'd strongly discourage (1) using internal functions (2) using `\exp_args:` on a document- or design-level function.

Comment: @ScottH. It's not that I think you're incorrect.  I really mean no disrespect of you.  Your answers definitely work.  But I felt I still wasn't understanding something and started playing around with defining new macros as in [this new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114896/expl-v-type-argument-no-fully-expanding-as-i-expected?lq=1) and felt that your solution still wasn't fully explaining my results.  I apologize if you feel slighted; that was not my intent.  :(

Comment: There is definitely much more going on in the "real" situation.  Otherwise, I would have written the code just as you have.  Perhaps I'm writing something a bit too complicated, but I don't think so.  I'll edit the above question to try to explain a bit.

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't feel slighted, all is good, I asked out of curiosity!  Joseph, Sorry to clutter your question, I probably should have asked on chat or somewhere, but thanks for indulging me.