# Expl V-type argument no fully expanding as I expected

Tags: expl3

This is related to an [earlier question of mine.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114868/expl-variable-assignments-not-behaving-as-i-expect)

I'm posting my own interpretation of what's happening hoping that if I'm wrong, someone will chime in an explain why.

The issue with `xparse`'s `\IfNoValue` does not hinge on passing an `n` type argument as @ScottH seems to be suggesting.  The issue seems to be buried deeper inside the definition of `\IfNoValue`.

The nice thing about `\IfNoValue` is that it is designed in a manner to register whether an argument was empty or not without the end-user being able to *accidentally* pass something through the argument that'll be interpreted as an empty argument.  Namely, `\IfNoValue{-NoValue-}` should register false.  This comes about through some fancy temporary assignment of lower case values and the use of a *weird* (`w`) type argument.

The following example illustrates what's happening:  (For the most part I'm following `xparse`'s lead in how I'm defining commands so as to mirror the issues from my earlier question as best as possible.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ae_experiment:w #1 DELIMITER { #1 }

\cs_new:Npn \ae_testing_weird:n #1 {
    \str_if_eq:onTF
        { \ae_experiment:w #1 DELIMITER }
        { Andrew }
        { \emph{moi} }
        { \textbf{not}~me }
}
\cs_new:Npn \ae_testing_ntype:n #1 {
    \str_if_eq:onTF
        { #1 }
        { Andrew }
        { \emph{moi} }
        { \textbf{not}~me }
}

\cs_new_eq:NN \testingWeird \ae_testing_weird:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \testingNtype \ae_testing_ntype:n

\NewDocumentCommand{\bypassWeird}{m}
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_bypass_tl {#1}
        \exp_args:NV \testingWeird \l_ae_bypass_tl
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Andrew}{}{Andrew}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
Func. Call      & \verb=Andrew=         & vs. & \verb=\Andrew=         \\\hline
\verb=Weird=    & \testingWeird{Andrew} &     & \testingWeird{\Andrew} \\
\verb=Ntype=    & \testingNtype{Andrew} &     & \testingNtype{\Andrew} \\
\verb=bypassed= & \bypassWeird{Andrew}  &     & \bypassWeird{\Andrew}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I expected the second and third line of this table to have the same results.  But it appears that `\exp_args:NV` only expanded `\l_ae_bypass` once to `\Andrew` and then no further.  Why?

Rewriting

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\Andrew}{}{Andrew}
```

or even

```
 \def\Andrew{Andrew}
```

or

```
 \xdef\Andrew{Andrew}
```

does not fix things.

Comment: I will try to work out what you are up to in the other question and give a 'proper' answer there. Note at this stage that `\exp_args:NV \testingWeird` is _strongly_ discouraged: you should not really need `\exp_args:` in code at all, as `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` should be used on appropriate code-level functions.

Comment: I only resorted to `\exp_args:` because that's what I seem to need to get things to work in my previous example.  I look forward to your answer to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what is supposed to happen: `V`-type expansion gives you the value stored inside a variable. The flow when you use

```
\bypassWeird{\Andrew}
```

is that `\l_ae_bypass` has content `\Andrew`. So when you do

```
\exp_args:NV \testingWeird \l_ae_bypass
```

this is converted to

```
\testingWeird \l_ae_bypass { \Andrew }
```

and results in a false result in your test. If you want exhaustive expansion, then you'll have to have

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_ae_bypass {#1}
```

but in your case that will still fail as you've defined `\Andrew` as a document command (non-expandable) rather than as a variable (expandable).

(As noted by Marco Daniel, the `expl3` convention is that code-level variable names *must* end with the type. So you should have `\l_ae_bypass_tl` here.)